# Why do I get a "failed to lock directory" error when installing packages on my work laptop

Tags: r, directory, install.packages

I've recently installed R + Rstudio on my work-laptop and now I'm trying to install packages. I have full authorisation in the map that I'm downloading the packages to. However, I keep on getting the following error:

```
    Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory                         
    ‘\\hltfs001\Home$\jolien.jansen\Documents\R\win-library\3.6’ for 
    modifying. Try removing 
    ‘\\hltfs001\Home$\jolien.jansen\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’
```

This error is accompanied by this error:

```
     Warning in install.packages :
     'lib = "\\hltfs001/Home$/jolien.jansen/Documents/R/win-library/3.6"' 
     is not writable
```

I've tried to install the packages in a different folder, which I'm also authorised to do, but that did not solve the issue.

I've googled the error and that gave me a couple of things to try.

At first I tried manually removing the LOCK folder, and restarting R. That did not help

Then I tried this code:

```
    unlink("/hltfs001/Home$/jolien.jansen/Documents/R/win- 
    library/3.6/00LOCK", recursive = TRUE)
```

Which again removed the LOCK folder, but didn't help with the error either

Finally I tried:

```
    install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no- 
    lock'))
```

But again, that gave me the same error.

Comment: What kind of windows path starts with `\\hltfs001/Home$`?

Comment: @Roland Looks like a network-shared drive or something, that is, not a local computer folder. My answer about syncing software on the local computer might possibly shed some light on this, if that applies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that my problem is that my 00LOCK folder was located within an automatic-syncing Dropbox folder. So, **I paused the Dropbox sync** and then the problem went away after I deleted the 00LOCK folder. Apparently, the Dropbox syncing was interfering with the file locking mechanism of the installation process. So, once I finished installing the packages, I resumed my Dropbox syncing.